# Trello OAuth 1.0 with python requests

Tags: python, oauth, python-requests, trello

I want to get private trello board data by url `https://trello.com/b/VLtX3aOw/board_name.json`

When I do `requests.get(json_url)` I get `unauthorized permission requested`
Cannot figure out how to use OAuth 1.0
I've already got api_key, token, and api_secret.

> **Copy comment**: get same error while trying:
>
> ```
> from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session 
>
> trl = OAuth1Session('trello_api_key', client_secret='trello_api_secret') 
> url = 'trello.com/b/VLtX3aOw/board_name.json' 
> r = trl.get(url)
> ```

Comment: Straight from the requests oauth docs: https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib

Comment: get same error while trying:

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

trl = OAuth1Session('trello_api_key', client_secret='trello_api_secret')

url = 'https://trello.com/b/VLtX3aOw/board_name.json'

r = trl.get(url)

Answer (score 1):

1. go to [`https://trello.com/app-key/`](https://trello.com/app-key/) and get api_key and api_secret
2. get a token with url `https://trello.com/1/authorize?expiration=1day&name=MyPersonalToken&scope=read&response_type=token&key={YourAPIKey}` Also you can use `expiration=never` instead of `1day`
3. use this code:

   `from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
   api_key = your_api_key
   api_secret = your_api_secret 
   token = your_token
   trello = OAuth1Session(api_key, api_secret, token)
   url = 'https://trello.com/b/VLtX3aOw/board_name.json'
   r = trello.get(url)
   print(r.json())`

Comment: Relevant [trello.com - authorization#section-using-basic-oauth](https://developers.trello.com/page/authorization#section-using-basic-oauth)

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I've search far and wide for an answer to this problem.